# What is the proper reading order for the Corpse Party mangas?

Tags: corpse-party

Of the mangas that are part of the Corpse Party franchise, what order should they be read in? Which of the series are one-shots/not relevant to the main plot?

Release order seems to be:

- Blood Covered
- Musume
- Another Child
- Book of Shadows
- Sachiko's Game of Love – Hysteric Birthday 2U  and Cemetery 0: Kaibyaku no Ars Moriend (released on the same day)

Should they be read in release order, or is there a chronological order that should be used instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.scribd.com/doc/157761684/Corpse-Party-Manga-Order) document uploaded to scribd, there is no 'true' order. Some of the manga are concurrent or they follow their own timeline. This is the (scribd document) author's suggested reading order:

- Corpse Party CEMETERY0 ~The Genesis of Ars Moriendi~

  > This manga gives you Naho Saenoki's backstory
- Corpse Party: Musume

  > A separate timeline from Blood Covered. It is based off of the PC-98 version of Corpse Party with influences from the remakes.
- Corpse Party: Blood Covered

  > Mainly based off of the PC and PSP versions.
- Corpse Party: Another Child

  > This manga is possibly concurrent with Blood Covered's timeline. It is recommend people read Blood Covered first before read Another Child in order to not be spoiled.
- Corpse Party: Coupling x Anthology

  > This manga is a collection of random stories that does not follow any specific timeline. Suggested reading after Blood Covered since it is based off of that.
- Corpse Party: Book of Shadows

  > This is the sequel to the Blood Covered manga.
- Corpse Party: Sachiko's Game of Love? Hysteric Birthday 2U

  > The events in this manga does not follow any specific timeline. Suggested reading after CEMETERY0, Blood Covered, and Book of Shadows to understand the cast of characters better.

Comment: Is the "author" in this context "the author of scribd document" or "the author of *Corpse Party*"? The mention of "my personal opinions on this matter" inside the document seems weird.

Comment: I've edited that to make it cleared. From what I can tell, there doesn't seem to be a 'correct' order, and the document does make it clear that this is their opinion. Most of what I found online was 'the order doesn't matter', but this document gave actual reasonings for their decisions so I went with that,